# Странная проблема с CSS background

Tags: css3

Имеется класс:

```css
.fold {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: -193px;
  background: url(/images/fold.png) no-repeat right 700px;
}
```

так все работает, но почему то в варианте ниже картинка не отображается

```css
.fold {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: -193px;
  background-image: url('/images/fold.png');
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: right;
  background-size: 700px;
}
```

подскажите пожалуйста в чем проблема?

Comment: Скорее всего дело в том что во-втором варианте, адрес картинки у вас находиться в апострофах ' ', уберите их, и все должно заработать. Так-же вы должны убедиться что картинка не отображается, может она просто уехала.

Comment: Пробовал с апострофами и без - нет разницы, но если убрать background-repeat, то картинка отображается

Comment: Значит она или улетает в какую-либо сторону, либо маленького размера, попробуйте убрать позиционирование.

Comment: @user296741 надо может `background-image: url('../images/fold.png');` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ошибка интерпретации в

```
background: url(/images/fold.png) no-repeat right 700px;
```

А именно в **`right 700px`**, это одно свойство `background-position`, которое браузер переписывает в **`background-position-y: 700px`**(а не `background-size`). Вы можете в этом сами убедиться зайдя во вкладку Computed из DevTools.

Comment: Спасибо огромное!!!